# Magento 2: Get Product Stock status details in Category List Product details Rest API

Tags: rest-api, category-products, magento2.3.0, stock-status, category-listing

I have checked `Category Products list API` and gives list of the categories products. But don't get stock item details in products details. I want to need stock item details in products details.

`Categories list products default API.`

> Method: GET
>
> Using API URL:
>   http://localhost/magentosample230/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=10&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=4&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq

If any have idea how to get stock item details in Category Products list page using Rest API.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Magento save different APi point for getting Stock data

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_23.html check this link..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added `stock_item` in Category List Product details Rest API. Update ExtensionPool data of `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface` and add `stock_item` data provider.

> File path: magento\app\code\Vendor\StockitemApi\registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_StockitemApi', __DIR__);
```

> File path: magento\app\code\Vendor\StockitemApi\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_StockitemApi" >
    </module>
</config>
```

> File path: magento\app\code\Vendor\StockitemApi\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="extensionActions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="read" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="stock_item" xsi:type="string">Vendor\StockitemApi\Model\ReadHandler</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> File path: magento\app\code\Vendor\StockitemApi\Model\ReadHandler.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\StockitemApi\Model;


class ReadHandler implements \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface
     */
    private $stockRegistry;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry     
    ) {

        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }
    /**
     * Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface
     * @param type $product
     * @param type $arguments
     */
    public function execute($product, $arguments = [])
    {
        if ($product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem() !== null) {
            return $product;
        }

        $stockItem =$this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId());
        $extensionAttributes = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes->setStockItem($stockItem);
        $product->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $product;        
    }

}
```

Comment: Tried this approach but don't see any data in extension attributes in Magento 2.2.x site. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [`/stockItems/:sku`](https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/admin-rest-api.html#operation/catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1GetStockItemBySkuGet) to fetch Stock information. In addition, optionally provide a `scopeId` to narrow the stock for a given store. So hence in your case:

`http://localhost/magentosample230/rest/V1/stockItems/:sku`

Comment: Yes. But I need stock status included in Categories List Products.

Comment: @KirtiNariya Fairly certain that's not possible out of the box, if you mean getting the Category Structure of Products + Stock Information in a single call

Comment: I not need Category Structure. But need stock status included category listing 
 Products.
Category Page: http://localhost/magentosample230/gear/watches.html
And need stock status in added with watches products.

Comment: @KirtiNariya Same thing but different terminology, you're specifying a category and it's relevant products "tagged" under that tree; alibet `products` queries Product Repository, whereas you're wanting product Inventory to be included.

Comment: I have to need  "stock_item" included in list of the products as a "extension_attributes".

Answer (score 0):

Using this API

http://localhost/magentosample230/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=10&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=4&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq

I got the **stock_item** product details but only using admin token.

My Question about how can i get **stock_item** using customer token?

Using Admin token  i am getting result of stock_item succcessfully:

**"stock_item": {
            "item_id": 1420,
            "product_id": 1417,
            "stock_id": 1,
            "qty": 1,
            "is_in_stock": true,
            "is_qty_decimal": false,
            "show_default_notification_message": false,
            "use_config_min_qty": true,
            "min_qty": 0,
            "use_config_min_sale_qty": 1,
            "min_sale_qty": 1,
            "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
            "max_sale_qty": 10000,
            "use_config_backorders": true,
            "backorders": 0,
            "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
            "notify_stock_qty": 1,
            "use_config_qty_increments": true,
            "qty_increments": 0,
            "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
            "enable_qty_increments": false,
            "use_config_manage_stock": true,
            "manage_stock": true,
            "low_stock_date": null,
            "is_decimal_divided": false,
            "stock_status_changed_auto": 0
        },
        "is_wishlist_product": false
    },**

BUT using customer token **stock_item** Array not display any values results comes blank.